# Create a random group allocation in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python script that ranks skiers on performance (column: "GJENNOMSNITT") and then creates two matched groups on GJENNOMSNITT: group1 and group 2. I use the following code to this end:

```
    def allokereGrupper(df1):
        df1 = df1.sort_values(by='GJENNOMSNITT', ascending=True)
        mask = np.arange(len(df1)) % 2
        group1 = df1.loc[mask == 0]
        print("gruppe 1:")
        print(group1)
        group2 = df1.loc[mask == 1]
        print("gruppe 2:")
        print(group2)
        return group1,group2
```

The problem with this script is that the best skiers will always be in the GROUP 1 because of mask == 0. Instead, I want this to be random. I have been coded in JavaScript for 4 months and I am not able to come up with a good solution to this problem in Python. Can someone help me?

Here is all my code and you should have access to the csv file that I am reading

resultater.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Resultat:

    def lastInnOgRydd(path, LagreCsv = False):
        df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=2, decimal=".")
        filt = df['FINISH'] == 'DNF'
        dnf = df[filt]
        dnf = dnf.replace('DNF', 1)
        if LagreCsv == True:
            dnf.to_csv('DNF.csv')
        df.replace('DNF', np.NaN, inplace=True)
        df.replace('GARBAGE GARBAGE', np.NaN, inplace=True) #Denne finnes det nok en bedre løsning på
        df.dropna(subset=['FINISH'], inplace=True)
        df.dropna(subset=['NAME'], inplace=True)
        return df

    def endreDataType(df):
        df["FINISH"] = df["FINISH"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
        df["INTER 1"] = df["INTER 1"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
        df["SECTION IM4-FINISH"] = df["SECTION IM4-FINISH"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].astype(int)
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].astype(str)
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].str.replace('11', 'COURSE 1')
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].str.replace('22', 'COURSE 2')
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].str.replace('33', 'COURSE 3')
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].str.replace('55', 'UTKJORING')
        df["COMMENT"] = df['COMMENT'].str.replace('99', 'STRAIGHT-GLIDING')
        pd.to_numeric(df['FINISH'], downcast='float', errors='raise')
        pd.to_numeric(df['INTER 1'], downcast='float', errors='raise')
        pd.to_numeric(df['SECTION IM4-FINISH'], downcast='float', errors='raise')
        return df

    def navnendringCommentTilCourse(df):
        df.rename(columns={'COMMENT': 'COURSE'}, inplace=True)
        return df

    def finnBesteRunder(df):
        grupper = df.groupby(['BIB#', 'COURSE'])
        bestruns = grupper['FINISH'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).mean()).reset_index()
        print(bestruns)
        df1 = bestruns.pivot('BIB#', 'COURSE', 'FINISH').reset_index()
        df1['GJENNOMSNITT'] = df1['COURSE 1'].add(df1['COURSE 2']).add(df1['COURSE 3']).div(3)
        #df1['PRESTASJON'] = df1['MEAN'].div(df1['STRAIGHT-GLIDING']) # fjerner denne nå, men må med i den ordentilige analysen
        return df1

    def allokereGrupper(df1):
        df1 = df1.sort_values(by='GJENNOMSNITT', ascending=True)
        mask = np.arange(len(df1)) % 2
        group1 = df1.loc[mask == 0]
        print("gruppe 1:")
        print(group1)
        group2 = df1.loc[mask == 1]
        print("gruppe 2:")
        print(group2)
        return group1,group2
```

main.py

```
from moduler import Resultat

path = "http://www.cmagelssen.no/pilot2.csv"

df = Resultat.lastInnOgRydd(path)
df = Resultat.endreDataType(df)
df = Resultat.navnendringCommentTilCourse(df)
df = Resultat.finnBesteRunder(df)
df = Resultat.allokereGrupper(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on my answer. I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the two groups to be *matched* in the sense that for every consecutive pair of skiers in the ranking list (`df1`) it is to be decided randomly (with equal probabilities) whether the higher ranked skier is allocated to group 1 and the lower ranked one to group 2 or vice versa.

A straightforward if not the most efficient way to achieve this is to use Python's standard `random` module to shuffle each pair of `mask` values after assigning the repeating 0-1 sequence to `mask`:

```py
import numpy as np
import random


def allokereGrupper(df):
    df = df.sort_values(by='GJENNOMSNITT', ascending=True)
    mask = np.arange(len(df)) % 2
    
    # new: for each pair of mask values, 
    #      randomly decide whether to swap them or not
    for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
        random.shuffle(mask[i:i+2])
    
    group1 = df.loc[mask == 0]
    print("gruppe 1:")
    print(group1)
    group2 = df.loc[mask == 1]
    print("gruppe 2:")
    print(group2)
    return group1, group2
```

Note that I changed the name of the argument to `df`, to make it more explicit that this is a general function. To make it even more general, you could pass the name of the column to sort by as an argument too.

Comment: def allokereGrupper(df1):
        df1 = df1.sort_values(by='GJENNOMSNITT', ascending=True)
        mask = np.arange(len(df1)) % 2
        print(mask)

        for i in range(0, len(df1), 2):
            random.shuffle(mask[i:i+2])

        group1 = df1.loc[mask == 0]
        group1['GRUPPE'] = 'BLOCKED'

        group2 = df1.loc[mask == 1]
        group2['GRUPPE'] = 'RANDOM'

        print(group1)
        print(group2)

Comment: like this? I edited my question; it was ambiguous what I wanted to accomplish. It was the second solution you came up with that I was interested in. I have a ranking list of athletes, and I want the RANDOM and BLOCKED groups to have app. equal performance level. It is for a learning experiment